# CSS: Bold decreases text height

Tags: css

I have applied custom CSS on the elements of my header

```
#AccessibleNav li .main_mega_heading.heading_color:hover, #regularMenu ul:not(.dropDown) li a:hover {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/search

For a reason I don't get (first time I see that when applying bold), the height of the text seems to be compressed on hover

[image]

Any idea of the origin? (I can't find any)

Is it how the font **Montserrat** behaves?

Is it possible to resolve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to the font `Montserrat`.

In the following line (from the code source of the website), you can see that `Montserrat` is imported once per weight (and imported twice by the way). `Montserrat:700` is not iso with `Montserrat:400`.

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i|Montserrat:400,700|Montserrat:400,700|Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Simply remove `Montserrat:700` and it will works.

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i|Montserrat:400|Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the diagnosis!
Since I'm using the CMS Shopify, how could I change this information?

Comment: one more thing: if I remove Montserrat:700 and keep Montserrat:400, then it's not bold anymore! I want to keep the bold effect, but with the same text height

Comment: Pascal you sure ? I tried. It seems to work. I guess it's handled by browser when no other weight is defined.

Comment: No idea about Shopify

Comment: oh ok I see what you mean, indeed I keep the bold effect with removing 700, but this bold effect is "light" since applied to 400 only.
Alright I'll just keep like that, thanks for all explanations :)